# How to control a circular interpolation using a reference point?

Tags: trigonometry, interpolation

```
r0 = 1 # radius of circle
w0 = ? # angle of interpolation

x0 = 0 # x-coordinate from center of circle
y0 = 0 # y-coordinate from center of circle

x1 = 3 # x-coordinate from reference point
y1 = 5 # y-coordinate from reference point

a0 = x0 + r0 * cos(t) # parametric equation for x
b0 = y0 + r0 * sin(t) # parametric equation for y

p0 = (x0, y0) # center of circle
p1 = (x1, y1) # reference point
q0 = (a0, b0) # circular interpolation
```

The angle of interpolation `w0` varies from `0` to `2pi`, effectively tracing out all points around the circumference of the circle with radius `r0` and with the help of parametric equations `a0` and `b0`. However, what would be an equation to obtain the angle of interpolation `w0` in such a way that the resulting angle is always within the range of `0` to `2pi` depending on the quadrant in which the reference point `p1` is located?

I tried using `arctan2(x,y)` but the output range of this function is from `-pi` to `pi` not from `0` to `2pi`.